# mark minimum in plot: minimum not located on plot line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to mark a minimum in a regular 2d-plot. The point appears yet is not exactly located on the line (see picture).

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cyYG.png)

Please see error list below. This is only an extract the actual list is larger.

```
`alphas = np.logspace(-7, 7, 100)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.plot(alphas, error_list)
min_x = np.argmin(error_list) + 1
min_y = np.min(error_list)
plt.scatter(min_x, min_y, c='r', label='minimum')
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('error')
plt.legend()`
```

Is the plot line somehow interpolated such that the actual minimum is not even on the line?

```
error_list = [599.7369583196087,
 599.7358790919635,
 599.7343845837856,
 599.7323150452208,
 599.7294493301322,
 411.311098098712,
 408.9114678388588,
 407.0602918272642,
 405.9342248895584,
 405.6778354210495,
 406.3581799120334,
 407.93048845402234,
 410.23594904410896,
 669.4637983239177]
```

Comment: You need to remove the `+1` in `min_x = np.argmin(error_list)` **and** use `plt.scatter(alphas[min_x], min_y, ...)`